# Where can I get reliable offline drivers for a PS3 Controller?

Tags: pc, controllers, motioninjoy-ds3tool

I know of two driver/software combos that allow me to use my PS3 controller as a PC gamepad:

- **MotionInJoy** - I am using this right now but I have an older version which I was able to install and use without an internet connection. (I've unfortunately lost the instructions on how to do it again so I can only get it to work on my main computer and not my laptop)
- **SIXAXIS** - Which is easier to use offline and easier to install, but I have to run a batch file every time the controller disconnects. It's not as robust as MotionInJoy, as it doesn't allow me to remap the buttons to key-presses (which is annoying, as some games such as Melty Blood don't seem to recognize some of the input values)

So I'm wondering if there is any other PS3 Controller Drivers out there which I can install offline and are more reliable.

I don't care if they are digitally signed or not since I can disable that dam system in Windows 7 easily enough.

I mainly use the controller for the following games:

- Melty Blood
- ePSXE (for playing Games incompatible with the PS3 like Final Fantasy 8)
- Kamidori Alchemy Miester (never got a controller to work for it but would love to have one)
- Megaman X3 PC

Comment: +1 I would also like a better solution than MotioninJoy's offline hack (on that note, if I remember correctly you had to copy the page files to the MotionInJoy directory, although the exact steps escape me as well)

Answer (score 8):

You may want to take a look at [XInput Wrapper for DS3](http://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-XInput-Wrapper-for-DS3-and-Play-com-USB-Dual-DS2-Controller). It does turn your PS3 controller into an XInput device so you can map the buttons basically in any application/game supporting the XInput library. Combined with [Pokopom's XInput Pad Plugin](http://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-Pokopom-KrossX-s-Pad-Plugin) you should be very fine. I haven't tried it for myself but I've heard from quite a few people that it works very well.

Comment: Is XInput specific to emulators or would this solution work with other games, Steam, etc? Just wondering as you only mention emulators in your answer.

Comment: This should work with everything supporting Microsoft's XInput library. Then again, since I don't use it, I couldn't possibly comment on it. I guess the emulator part was a Freudian slip - I'll edit it out.

Comment: Cool, thanks for clarifying! Have a +1 :)

Comment: @Alex: It works with Steam and is recognized as a usual XInput device. It also works perfectly with an additional XBox360 gamepad, so you can use whatever gamepad you want without installing/uninstalling drivers (something MotionJoy couldn't accomplish).

Answer (score 7):

I recommend installing the MotionJoy drivers and using [Better DS3](http://betterds3.ciebiera.net/) to actually manage the controller:

[image]

Better DS3 has a simpler, better interface but does all the things Motionjoy's DS3 tool does. You still have to install the *drivers* from MotionJoy but Better DS3 can be used offline. Once you install the drivers you can simply use Better DS3 at all times to replace the DS3tool configuration. Also, no nasty ads in Better DS3, unlike Motionjoy's solution.

Since you're using the motionjoy drivers, your PS3 controller can be used without running anything like a batch file every time you plug it in/turn it on. It sounds like Better DS3 even handles Bluetooth pairing so you should never need to launch MotionJoy or connect to the internet after downloading.

Comment: ahhhh, but the problem is installing the drivers, i dont have any use for DS3_Tool except to just start up when i am using the drivers, but i have posted on the blog asking if there is any plans to allow Better DS3 to install the drivers offline so i'll keep an eye on this tool

Comment: @Memor-X I'm not sure what the problem is, you dont' actually have to use DS3 tool in any way, just install motionjoy for the drivers (I am pretty sure it can be installed offline) and then use Better DS3 at all times after that.

Comment: The instructions on the site for Motion Joy say you have to use DS3_Tool to install the drivers and getting that to work offline is a problem, if i can install the drivers without DS3_Tool then that's a good thing and i would love to know how

Comment: @Memor-X can the PC literally never, not even once, touch the internet for one instant? Because you literally only have to install the drivers once and then use the Better DS3 tool forever.

Comment: To connect my PC to the Internet would require me to unplug it and move it to another room and have everything connected on the floor then move it back, it does help that when I plug stuff into the back of it my head is placed on the wall as a support as I lean down and even then I need to blindly plug things up. In my new place I'll have the net setup next to my PC but even though I thought I'd be there in march it's now June and its still not even done and I have no hope of it being done before the end of the year now

Comment: As for my laptop, it can connect to the Internet via wireless but even when I installed the latest version of the drivers by the net it just sat at that installation screen with no confirmation message, if I had an offline installer for drivers then there is no variable about the server or net connection

Comment: I should also note that even though my PC already has the drivers working on it, an offline installation would be useful if I go to upgrade my PC or I have to do a fresh install of the opposing system

Answer (score 3):

There's an [Offline MotioninJoy mod](http://forums.motioninjoy.com/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=3551) that lets you use the program without an internet connection and still be able to install the drivers. Sometimes you need to minimize and restore the MotioninJoy window to get the user interface to appear, but otherwise it works well enough.

Once you've installed the drivers you can either keep using the offline mod or install [Better DS3](http://betterds3.ciebiera.net/). I suggest the latter since Better DS3 is far more stable and user-friendly than MotioninJoy.